# private docker registery server pulls from docker hub if image not exists in the registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have a docker registry server for my team and I want to do the following when a user pulls image from the registry:

1. Check if the image exists in my registry.
2. If yes, return the image from my registry and end here.
3. If no, try to pull the image from the official docker hub registry. cache the image in my registry for further use and then return it to the user and end here.

In my case, I want my docker register as a bridge. Not only it could store private images, but also cache the images to save the bandwidth.

Do you have any idea to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have recently implemented such a use case, below is the configuration you have to use to make that happen.

```
proxy:
  remoteurl: https://registry-1.docker.io
  username: [username]
  password: [password]
```

Add this configuration in your `config.yml` file, which you will be using with your registry.

Update the above config with your docker hub credentials.

This use case in particular is known as **Registry as a pull through cache**.

Official Docker documentation link : https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - There is no out of the box option provided  by Docker. You have to run the docker pull command twice.

1. Pull it from your local repo using the below syntax.

```
   $ docker pull myregistry.local:5000/testing/test-image
```

2. If the above fails, pull it from docker repo.

```
 $ docker pull  test-image
```

Refer [official docs here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/).